# Python how to calcualate average of individual list of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list in a list with a lot of data:

```
data =  [ [4,25,1,6,3,1,6,...],[45,2,1,5,6,20,29],[491,5,195,239,194,09]
         ..[2,1,5,6,1,95] ]
```

and what I've been trying to figure out how to do is calculate the mean of each individual list and turn it into a column of data looking like this:

```
List# average
1     (Mean value of the first list)
2     (Mean value of the second list)
....
15    (mean value of the 15th list)
```

I've tried to put in to loop of iteration like this:

```
def average(data)
    for i in range(16):
        total = 0.0
        for x in data[i]:
            total = total + x
    return total / len(data[i])
```

but it only calculate the mean of the first list so far. I also want to calculate the mean of the each of those individual list with the first piece of data sliced off but I don't know how to do that with list in a list.

Edit: changed as suggested but I still have only 1 result from the function, not the average from every sublist.

Comment: Your return statement is indented inside the second for loop. It needs to be outside of it, and inside the first for loop.

Comment: Having said that, you should use Python's built-in `sum` function. It's written in C, so it'll be faster than what you've written in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Replace **numb** by **x**.

And you should unindent your **return** by one.

Unfortunately, more problem might arise depending of your goals. :)

EDIT : I'm feeling generous

```
def average(listOfList):
    for index, listOfNumbers in listOfList:
        print (  "{}\t{}".format(index, sum(listOfNumbers) / len(listOfNumbers)) )
```

Comment: I've tried to unindented by one and replace numb by x but still no lucks. My goal is find out the mean values of each individual list and put into a column as I illustrated.

Comment: Appreciated your generosity, but I've encountered a syntax error while compling your codes at "{}\t{}"

Comment: If you're using python 3, add parenthesis around the print argument. I'll modify it so you understand.

Answer (score 0):

the problem with your code is an indentation error. your `return` statement is indented into your `while` loop. if you fix that it should work. however it is better to do this using an average function that finds the average of each sublist, and a list comprehension.

```
def average(l):
    return sum(l)/len(l) #float(len(l)) if python 2.x

new_list = [average(lst[1:]) for lst in list] # since you want to cut off the first value.
```

also, you shouldn't use `list` as a variable, as it reassigns the builtin.

Comment: Yes, I'll change it to
      data = [ [ [4,25,1,6,3,1,6,...],[45,2,1,5,6,20,29],[491,5,195,239,194,09]
         ..[2,1,5,6,1,95] ]

but I'm getting errors with your codes, not sure what went wrong.  is "lst" = to 1st or lst? and where is that from?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the builtin `sum` and `len` functions:

```
l = [ [4,25,1,6,3,1,6],[45,2,1,5,6,20,29],[491,5,195,239,194,9],[2,1,5,6,1,95]]
new_l = {'List {}'.format(i):sum(a)/float(len(a)) for i, a in enumerate(l, start=1)}
```

Output:

```
{'List 4': 18.333333333333332, 'List 2': 15.428571428571429, 'List 3': 188.83333333333334, 'List 1': 6.571428571428571}
```

Edit: to remove the first value in each list:

```
l = [ [4,25,1,6,3,1,6],[45,2,1,5,6,20,29],[491,5,195,239,194,9],[2,1,5,6,1,95]]
new_l = [i[1:] for i in l]
```

Output:

```
[[25, 1, 6, 3, 1, 6], [2, 1, 5, 6, 20, 29], [5, 195, 239, 194, 9], [1, 5, 6, 1, 95]]
```

Edit: Rounding the dictionary values:

```
l = [ [4,25,1,6,3,1,6],[45,2,1,5,6,20,29],[491,5,195,239,194,9],[2,1,5,6,1,95]]
new_l = {'List {}'.format(i):round(sum(a)/float(len(a)), 2) for i, a in enumerate(l, start=1)}
```

Output:

```
{'List 4': 18.33, 'List 2': 15.43, 'List 3': 188.83, 'List 1': 6.57}
```

Comment: I received TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable error

Comment: @Onggia the code posted above is valid and runs, however, how are you using it in your own code?

Comment: @oh nevermind, I have my list named something different. And your codes worked fine, thank you!

What I'm doing is self-learning from an assignment from my textbook. But I'm not clear on what you did there, could you either explain that to me?(I don't understand the ".format(i)" "a inenumerate(l,start =1)") and I'm also new to coding in general, how would I able to put in display in column as showed above in my og post?

Comment: or a different version of your code that input it out into a list of mean values would be better for me.

Comment: @Onggia glad to help! This problem utilizes dictionary comprehension, which allows us to create a dictionary in one line. `.format(i)` precisely and elegantly inserts characters into a formatting string, the locations of which denoted by `{}`. `enumerate` iterations over an iterable, returning the current index and value corresponding to that index. Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Yes, I how would I able to slice any list in a list, for example, remove the first value in all the list. Thank you very much for helping me with this, by the way!

Comment: How would I able to round dictionary values, I've searched around and it seem I'll need to rewrite the line?

Comment: WIth dictionary, how can I access the data(in order to create max or mean) or reuse it for different formula, for exampe: finding standard deviation.

Comment: @Onggia are you referring to this dictionary: `{'List 4': 18.33, 'List 2': 15.43, 'List 3': 188.83, 'List 1': 6.57}`?

Answer (score 0):

Other answer will solve your issue , Just wanted to let you know that you can do in one line without any loop :

```
data=[ [4,25,1,6,3,1,6],[45,2,1,5,6,20,29],[491,5,195,239,194,9],[2,1,5,6,1,95] ]

print(list(map(lambda x:sum(x)/len(x),data)))
#do your stuff with this result
```

output:

```
[6.571428571428571, 15.428571428571429, 188.83333333333334, 18.333333333333332]
```